# Mac OSX App Drop Down menu

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

How do I create a drop down menu that I can add as a subview to an NSView in an OSX app? I've been looking online and can't really find any information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

This [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MenuList/Articles/DisplayContextMenu.html) demonstrates how to create a menu on *mouse down*:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSMenu *theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Beep" action:@selector(beep:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Honk" action:@selector(honk:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:1];
    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:theMenu withEvent:theEvent forView:self];
}
```

but there are other ways of doing it as well, but it depends exactly how and when you want the menu displayed.